# Let $\varphi:L\to L$ an automorphism. If $\varphi$ fix a root, is it the identity?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $L/K$ a field extension, $\varphi:L\longrightarrow L$ an automorphism and $\alpha \in L$. Let $P$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha $ over $K[X]$ and $\alpha _1,...,\alpha _n$ all roots of $P$ (not necessarily in $L$). I know the $\sigma $ act transitively on the roots of $P$. I was curious about something (may be I'm wrong), but I have the intuition that if $P$ fix one root of $P$ in $L$, then it fix all roots in $L$, i.e. it's the identity. Is it true ore false ? And if it's false, is there a certain condition that yield this result true ? (I was wondering about something like normal extension).

Answer (score 2):

If $L$ is Galois, then this is true iff $K(\alpha)$ already contains all the roots $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ (which it usually doesn't).  Indeed, we may assume $L=K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ since every automorphism of $K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ extends to $L$.  We are then asking whether every automorphism of $L$ that fixes the subfield $K(\alpha)$ is the identity.  By the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, this is true iff $K(\alpha)=L$.

For an explicit example, let $K=\mathbb{Q}$, let $P(x)=x^4-2$, let $L\subset\mathbb{C}$ be the splitting field of $K$, and let $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$ (the positive real $4$th root).  Then there is an automorphism of $L$ that swaps the two square roots of $-\sqrt{2}$, but fixes the two square roots of $\sqrt{2}$ (including $\alpha$).